# What is the scheduled job linked to Scheduled SMS Reminders?

Tags: scheduled-reminders, sms

In CiviCRM 4.5, you are now able to create Scheduled Reminders to be delivered by SMS as well as email.

We're having an issue with these reminders, however, I'm not sure which scheduled job triggers their delivery?

1. Send Scheduled SMS - Sends out scheduled SMS
   I thought this was the one to trigger bulk SMS deliveries that have been set up, the same and the Scheduled Email job?
2. Send Scheduled Reminders - Sends out scheduled reminders via email
   Refers specifically to the delivery of scheduled reminders, but the description refers to email only. Has the description just not been updated?

Would be really grateful if someone could point be in the right direction to investigate the other issue we're having.

Heather.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer your direct question, but I have an alternative solution.

We are using the extension CiviRules and the extensions SMS API and Email API to achieve the same.

Then you have the possibilities to set certain triggers/events, and conditions. At the end you can set different actions, and one of them is sending sms automatically via the SMS API

We are on 4.4, so you need to try it yourself though...